# AQL query takes 30+ seconds

Tags: arangodb, aql

I really need to optimize this, but having trouble.

```
FOR a IN accounts
      FILTER a.keywordsystem==true
        FOR k IN rotationpicks FILTER k.apikey==a._key 
             LET stats = (  FOR s IN rotationstats FILTER s.keywordid == k.keywordid AND s.apikey==k.apikey AND 
                  s.date == DATE_FORMAT(DATE_UTCTOLOCAL(DATE_ADD(DATE_NOW(),0,'hour'), "UTC"),'%yyyy-%mm-%dd')
                  COLLECT kwid=s.keywordid AGGREGATE clicks=sum(s.clicks)
                  RETURN clicks)
              LET clicks = (stats[0]==null?0:stats[0])
              SORT k.rpc DESC 
              LET final = MERGE(k, {clicks:clicks})
        RETURN final
```

This part is the problem, there is only about 10 million records in that collection.

```
                  s.date == DATE_FORMAT(DATE_UTCTOLOCAL(DATE_ADD(DATE_NOW(),0,'hour'), "UTC"),'%yyyy-%mm-%dd')
                  COLLECT kwid=s.keywordid AGGREGATE clicks=sum(s.clicks)
                  RETURN clicks)
```

When I remove the date filter:
s.date == DATE_FORMAT(DATE_UTCTOLOCAL(DATE_ADD(DATE_NOW(),0,'hour'), "UTC"),'%yyyy-%mm-%dd') Then it only takes a 1-2 seconds.  I have an index on that date field and the format is stored in YYYY-MM-DD.   Not sure why it's taking so long when adding in the date criteria.

Comment: Can you please include the profile output as well as the list of indexes of all the involved collections?